# Retrive row only if the column 'date' with the latest value have an another column not NULL

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

Let's say I have this table

```
id  | value | date       | result
----+-------+------------+--------
1   | 1     | 2017-01-01 | NULL 
2   | 1     | 2017-01-02 | NULL 
3   | 2     | 2017-01-03 | NULL 
4   | 1     | 2017-01-04 | NULL  
5   | 2     | 2017-01-05 | NULL 
6   | 3     | 2017-01-06 | NULL 
7   | 1     | 2017-01-07 | NULL
```

My goal is to retrieve every "value" for which the last "date" has a "result" equal to NULL.

For instance, with the previous table, my result should look like this:

```
id  | value | date       | result
----+-------+------------+--------
5   | 2     | 2017-01-05 | NULL
6   | 3     | 2017-01-06 | NULL
7   | 1     | 2017-01-07 | NULL
```

The query I use is:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (value) * 
FROM table 
WHERE result IS NULL 
ORDER BY value ASC, date DESC
```

But when I got this table:

```
id  | value | date       | result
----+-------+------------+--------
1   | 1     | 2017-01-01 | NULL
2   | 1     | 2017-01-02 | NULL
3   | 2     | 2017-01-03 | NULL
4   | 1     | 2017-01-04 | NULL
5   | 2     | 2017-01-05 | something
6   | 3     | 2017-01-06 | NULL
7   | 1     | 2017-01-07 | NULL
```

I obtain

```
id  | value | date       | result
----+-------+------------+--------
4   | 2     | 2017-01-04 | NULL
6   | 3     | 2017-01-06 | NULL
7   | 1     | 2017-01-07 | NULL
```

instead of

```
id  | value | date       | result
----+-------+------------+--------
6   | 3     | 2017-01-06 | NULL
7   | 1     | 2017-01-07 | NULL
```

I tried to use group by / having, but it was more a disaster than else.
Is this impossible to do or I'm missing something really simple?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the condition outside the query:

```
select *
from (
    select distinct on (value) * 
    from my_table 
    order by value asc, date desc
    ) s
where result is null
order by id

 id | value |    date    | result 
----+-------+------------+--------
  6 |     3 | 2017-01-06 | 
  7 |     1 | 2017-01-07 | 
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Okay, I am so focused on doing it in one query that I forgot that. By curiosity, is there a way to do it in "one" query ?

Comment: It's a single query with a derived table. You have to use a derived table as the filter must be applied to an earlier obtained data.

Comment: From my point of view, it's 2 query : one for having the list of last value, another for filtering NULL value. Well, I could have searched a long time ... thank you, I will keep this in mind.

Comment: Still it's a single query, one can say, executed in two stages (steps). Alternative solutions using `group by` and aggregates also need at least two steps.